# Use back button to show site list on Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-interface

As phones keep getting bigger reaching the edge of the phone keeps getting harder.

While browsing/reading questions on a phone (yes, typically I'm a lurker) it is hard to open sites list. Suppose I'm holding the phone in my right hand - there are two ways I can achieve this:

- By shifting the phone in my right hand
- By using my left hand (which may be busy)

One way to solve this usability issue would be to allow the back button on the main screen to, instead of immediately closing the application, open the sites list and only if it is opened close the app. A good example of this behavior is the [Feedly mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devhd.feedly&hl=en).

Point to consider is whether this will impact users who actually use the back button to close apps.